# PL/SQL: How to insert all records from table type to another table without for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

I have probably trivial problem but I can't nail the logic quite right.

I have following types:

```
create or replace TYPE test_rec FORCE
   AS OBJECT (ref_id NUMBER (20)
             ,ref_type VARCHAR2 (4));
```

```
create or replace TYPE test_ref_tbl FORCE
   AS TABLE OF test_rec;
```

and actual table

```
CREATE TABLE my_tbl
( id number(10) NOT NULL,
  ref_id varchar2(20) NOT NULL,
  ref_type varchar2(4),
  CONSTRAINT my_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Now, in one procedure I get variable `test_ref_tbl` with data and I have to insert everything to `my_tbl`, also id should be generated from sequence.

I managed to do this quite easily with for loop

```
FOR i IN 1 .. test_ref_tbl.COUNT LOOP
  INSERT INTO my_tbl(id
                    ,ref_id
                    ,ref_type)
  VALUES (my_test_sequence.NEXTVAL
         ,test_ref_tbl(i).ref_id
         ,test_ref_tbl(i).ref_type
);
END LOOP;
```

and everything works fine, but I got alot of flack for inserting data in for loop, I'm not plsql developer so maybe my colleagues are making my job harder just for the hell of it.

But to get back on topic, is there a way to do this without for loop?

Thanks

Comment: "I'm not plsql developer so maybe my colleagues are making my job harder just for the hell of it" hahaha ... love that, thanks for the laugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Here's an example:

Creating test case first:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_rec FORCE AS OBJECT
  2  (
  3     ref_id NUMBER (20),
  4     ref_type VARCHAR2 (4)
  5  );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_ref_tbl FORCE AS TABLE OF test_rec;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE my_tbl
  2  (
  3     id         NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
  4     ref_id     VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
  5     ref_type   VARCHAR2 (4),
  6     CONSTRAINT my_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE my_test_sequence;

Sequence created.
```

As data source, I'm using Scott's `DEPT` table.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_tab  test_ref_tbl;
  3  BEGIN
  4     SELECT test_rec (deptno, SUBSTR (dname, 1, 4))
  5       BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab
  6       FROM dept;
  7
  8     -- this is what you're looking for
  9     INSERT INTO my_tbl (id, ref_id, ref_type)
 10        SELECT my_test_sequence.NEXTVAL, t.*
 11          FROM TABLE (l_tab) t;
 12  END;
 13  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT * FROM my_tbl;

        ID REF_ID               REF_
---------- -------------------- ----
         1 10                   ACCO
         2 20                   RESE
         3 30                   SALE
         4 40                   OPER

SQL>
```